# Index out of range for string of length 1

Tags: python

I am practicing recursive function for reversing a string.
Whenever there is no space between quotation marks in `str1 == ''`, the code works fine.
However, if I do put a space in between the quotes in `str1 == ' '`, I get an error: String index out of range. (since both indices -1 and 0 are valid for str1 with space in quotes)
I do not understand why this error occurs and how to eliminate it.

```
def reverse(str1):
    if str1 ==''
        return str1
    else: 
        return str1[-1]+reverse[:-1]


def main():
    str1 = input ('Enter string')
    result = reverse(str1)
    print ('Reverse of string is ', result)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I'm getting `'function' is not subscriptable` and `SytanxError`, are you sure this is the correct code?

Comment: I just spent a full minute staring at this question trying to figure out what semicolons you were talking about and finally realized that you mean quotation marks.

Comment: Maybe you meant `return str1[-1]+reverse(str1[:-1])`?

Comment: **Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: a semicolon is `;`, a quotation mark is `'`.  :)

The strings `''` and `' '` are not the same -- one is an empty string, the other is a string that is one character long.

Your recursive function works by slicing the string into smaller and smaller pieces.  Once it reaches an empty string, it needs to return instead of slicing it any further.  This is called a "base case" -- a special check for the case that you can't solve by recursing further.

When you change your "base case" check so that it no longer catches the empty string (`''`), it breaks the function, because it will then continue on to attempt to slice, and that raises the exception you're seeing.  The value of `str1` that causes your function to break is `''` (no space), and your recursion will always end in that value, so making this change to your code will always break it.

Answer (score 2):

You could change reverse function like this:

```
return str1[::-1]
```

This will reverse irrespective of the length of string. Hope this works.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working. If I have space in between the quotation marks if str==' ', I get the error string index out of range. If I do not have space in between quotation marks if str=='', I get the error Maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison.

Answer (score 1):

```
chars = [char for char in str1]
chars.reverse()
print(''.join(chars))
```

Answer (score 1):

As Sam Stafford said in another answer and the comment from gilch, changing the base case and recursively calling the function on the string without the last character will allow the function to work.  Something like:

```
def reverse(str1):
    if len(str1) == 1:
        return str1
    else:
        return str1[-1] + reverse(str1[:-1])
```